# `nohup`ing an already-running process by PID (akin to AIX nohup -p)

Tags: linux, bash

I have a situation where I'm not able to run `nohup -p <processid>` in Linux RHEL 6.6 box it says this option is not supported. I read the manpage and in Linux it had only `--help` and `--version` as options in Linux.

Is there any other alternative for `nohup -p`, to allow an already-running process to survive an exit of the running terminal?

Comment: ...also, frankly, `nohup` is generally pretty useless. Redirect stdin, stdout and stderr to a non-TTY source; tell the shell to set the HUP signal up to be discarded, use the `disown` builtin to remove a job from your shell's process table, and you've accomplished everything `nohup` would otherwise do without needing to use the command.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so 3 steps, that can be done in one `nohup`?

Comment: Ahh, but your three steps force the user to think about what they're doing and make explicit decisions, whereas your "one `nohup`" has an utterly brain-dead `nohup.out` redirection target default.

Answer (score 4):

Part of this is easy: To remove a job from your shell's process table, you can use `disown`.

The part that's *not* easy is redirecting stdout and stderr away from the TTY. To do that, you can use `gdb` to take control of the process and tell it to replace stdin, stdout and stderr (note that you'll need to be sure that this is also done on other subprocesses or threads that likewise need to survive the exit operation):

```
# for an instance of /path/to/program with PID 1234

# note that this is intended to be a transcript of content typed at a prompt -- it isn't a
# working shell script, since the commands after "gdb" are to be run *by gdb*, not the
# shell.

gdb /path/to/program
attach 1234
p dup2(open("/dev/null", 1), 0)
p dup2(open("stdout-file", 1), 1)
p dup2(open("stderr-file", 1), 2)
detach
quit
```

This [has been automated](http://www.isi.edu/~yuri/dupx/) as a tool called `dupx`.